# PHP database comparing hashed login with db

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to build a login feature but without a registration system. This presents an issue as I am not sure how to make hashing compatible between mysql and php.

My **PHP** code:

```
    if (password_verify($upass, 'sha256') && $count == 1){
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['uid'];
        header("Location:profilepage.php");
    }
    else {
     //SPLOSIONS!!
    }
```

`$upass` represents a `POST` on my form input, where users enter their given password.

My attempt at hashing password in **MySQL**:

```
 UPDATE users SET `userpassword` = SHA2(`userpassword`, 256)
```

The `userpassword` matches my `userpassword` column on my database, which I have hashed with SHA2.

The problem here is that my `password_verify` code on PHP appears incompatible with my updated hashed password on MySQL. As a result I run into my `else` command, rather than the code I want.

Was wondering how to make my MySQL password column compatible with my PHP code, or vice versa, or if there is a more practical approach to this.

Comment: You need to use `password_verify`'s paired companion function `password_hash` to hash the password, on the PHP side, and you should use the default bcrypt algorithm for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

Added the following code:

```
    $hashslingingslasher = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Then called it via:

```
    if (password_verify($upass, $hashslingingslasher) && $count == 1){
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['uid'];
        header("Location:userpage.php");
    }
```

Comment: Please don't tell me  those two `$upass` variables are one and the same?! I.e. you're hashing the `$upass` variable and then immediately verify it…?!

Comment: that's where im a tad confused. my main goal here is to verify a hashed password, which i set in my db via mysql. since i do not intend on having a registration system, my login credentials are made in mysql and hashed therein. to ensure compatibility, i have taken to hashing the user's input and verifying it against my hashed password. i imagine a criticism here might be that hashing the input defeats the purpose of hashing?

Comment: You have to verify the hash you store in your database using the same hashing mechanism that created it. If you create hashes as SHA256, then you can't use `password_verify` to verify them, because they are/use two completely different algorithms. You can only use hashes created with `password_hash` in `password_verify`. You can only use SHA256 to verify SHA256 hashes. If you wrote something that somehow crosses those two it inherently *cannot* work and must therefore be nonsense.

Comment: Additionally, SHA256 hashes are extremely weak for password storage, you should not use it. `password_hash` hashes are very strong. You should be creating your password hashes using `password_hash` and store them in the database instead of what you're doing at the moment.

Comment: so since my passwords are hashed via UPDATE users SET `userpassword` = SHA2(`userpassword`, 256) is there anything you would change about this? going back to my answer i have verified that i am using `password_hash` instead of `256`

Comment: Again: don't create passwords via `SHA2(...)` in the database, create them using `password_hash` in PHP and insert them into the database. If your current password hashes are SHA256 and your verification is `password_verify` *and it actually "works"*, I guarantee you you're doing something completely nonsensical and you're probably not actually verifying anything.

Comment: fair enough. so when people make passwords into a db without a registration form, are they doing so by running a temporary php page?

Comment: Maybe? Heck if I know what "people" do… :P